# Does jQuery apply CSS3 for animation?

Tags: jquery, css

It seems that jQuery do the animation by changing the element's margin, does it apply any CSS3 stuff such as transition?

Comment: Even if it does, transitions aren't the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  Just look at http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js -- `transition` does not appear anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, and this sucks. Here's a demo comparing the speed of transitions with jQuery: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/demos/speed.php.